Escaping ban message of we are no longer accepting answers from your account
When I tried to post an answer, I received the following message:

Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because
most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer
the question. See the Help Center to learn more.

How can I fix this?

your reputation score needs to go up with better quality https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/482816/qgis-show-only-one-label/ (your rep went down as it was downvoted by community members then deleted.) please read the guidelines https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Having had a look at your past deleted answers, it appears that you are using the space for Answers to ask questions or make comments on Questions.  Only one (of 5) appears to be an actual answer.  Answers are for answers only.  Use comments to request further info.

Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place:

Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban answers from
accounts that have posted numerous low-quality answers in the past.
These filters help keep the quality of our sites high.
Users who are banned from answering see the following error message
when trying to post a new answer:
Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because
most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer
the question. See the Help Center to learn more.
Answer bans do not affect other privileges, such as commenting or
voting, and there is no indication to the rest of the community that a
particular user has been banned from posting.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans#:~:text=Stack%20Exchange%20does%20not%20lift,expire%20or%20%22time%20out%22.
you need to improve your existing posts before this will be removed

There are detailed explanations of why users see such messages and their options to escape them at What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?
In particular, I would draw your attention to:

Automatic bans never expire or "time out". This means that you cannot
simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action,
you will never be allowed to freely post again. The only way for the
ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other
ways.
Moderators cannot lift the ban.

